# Capturing Reassigned Approval Request

Tags: apex, trigger, community

Is it possible to  write some logic to capture the Reassigned Approval Request.?

Basically i want to see, how many times an opportunity has been reassigned... and whats the elapse time per instance.... There is more to to this requirement so i cannot directly use the Sales force Reporting on Approval History.

Could you pl suggest possibility to achieve this...

I have tried below, but couldn't see it to be working:  Any suggestions,pl share.

- I dont see Process Builder or flow or Trigger to be supported on ProcessInstance Object.
- Wrote a PB on opportunity, but in case of reassignment i can't get an edit operation on Oportunity to fire my code....Am not sure, how can i invoke my code in case of Reassignment..

E.g:  User A has submitted the Approval request to User B initially.
Then User A reassigned it to User C.

I want to capture this reassignment details in my report to see, how many times the record was reassigned. 
Hope this clarifies my question further

Comment: You can refer this post [approval process current step](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/126661/query-current-step-number-for-approval-process/126687#126687)

Comment: Thanks for responding Santanu.. however am not looking for getting the SOQL to know the relation between the Approval Tables...I do understand them.                  Sorry if am not coming across clearly,.....I want to capture the Reassignment of the user on each selection of Approver manually.

Comment: Your answer would be much improved if you [edit] your post with concrete examples of what you've tried.

Comment: @AdrianLarson : I have edited my post, pl check. THe details on what i have tried is mentioned as bullet points.  and bullet point is a combination of Process Builder and Apex. that works when the approval request is submitted, but not for reassignment- as reassignmnet happends on a different object[thats not considered by process builder]

Comment: @user10727: Do you have any update to this ? Any ideas to proceed